# swing: JPanel vs. modal/modeless dialog?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jdialog

I want to implement some functionality in a library and make it available as a GUI building block for my applications. I think I would like to implement it as something that extends a `JPanel`, so it can be embedded as a component in other windows.

Is there a reason I should use a `JDialog` instead? How easy is it to create a `JDialog` which displays a `JPanel` along with minimal other appropriate components? (e.g. just a border/closebox/etc for modeless dialog; for modal, the same + an OK/Cancel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should extend JDialog **only** if you want a Dialog, and if you want just a Panel that you can use in other Windows or Frames you should extend JPanel.

Yes, it is easy to create an JDialog just containing a JPanel with a border, closebox and OK/Cancel, both modal and not modal.

Have a look at [How to Make Dialogs](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) and [How to Use Panels](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would make it a `JPanel`.  That way you could reuse it in other components or drop it into a `JFrame`  (by calling `setContentPane`) if you want to run it as a standalone.  The only reason for you to *need* a `JDialog` is if you want to make your component modal.